# Identity authentication in anonymous public key encryption

Tags: public-key, authenticated-encryption

In a similar anonymous PKE based on D-H key exchange, in a many-to-one (one-to-many) case, is there any way to implement authentication without revealing the identity of the sender (receiver)? Could you recommend some papers?

Comment: Similar to what exactly?